# Custom node template with related node teasers

Tags: theming

I have a custom node (article) template file working fine, and I want to show related nodes (events) in their teaser format. I have been doing this in my node--article.tpl.php file like this:

```
foreach ($field_related_event as $event_node){
    print render(node_view(node_load($event_node['nid']), 'teaser')); 
}
```

I wanted to add a second teaser format for events (`teaser_fancy`) and downloaded "Entity view modes" thinking I would be able to do something like this:

```
foreach ($field_related_event as $event_node){
    print render(node_view(node_load($event_node['nid']), 'teaser_fancy')); 
}
```

But now I read that node_view can only use teaser and full, and it's probably not a good idea to render relationships in my template this way. What's the recommended way to go about this? Should I create an Events Fancy view and use views_embed_view instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid "view_mode" should work with [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) and that approach looks reasonable.

However, if it's proving problematic, you can also use Views with `views_embed_view`

e.g

```
print views_embed_view('viewname', 'display_id', $node->nid); // node id contextual filter
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I suspected. Do you think there is a big downside to using rendering the way I am is I want all related items?